# jQuery How to retrieve the name of an input text field using JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var pValue = $(".blah").find("p").html();
        alert(" Information in Paragraph tag is ### " + pValue);`enter code here`

    $(".blah").find($("input:text")).each(function(){
        alert("Value inside the Input text field is #### " + this.value);
    });
}); 

  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="blah">
      <p>he he he</p>
      <input "type = text name ="userName" value = "abc"/>
      <input "type = text name ="id" value = "xyz"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

When i run the above HTML code i get the following alerts

- Information in Paragraph tag is ### he he he
- Value inside the Input text field is #### abc
- Value inside the Input text field is #### xyz

I want to retrieve the input text field names (username and id) and place it in the alerts dynamically so that my alerts look as shown below. I want this functionality because if the user enters his username and not the id. i want to display that his id is empty.

- Information in Paragraph tag is ### he he he
- Value inside the userName is #### abc
- Value inside the id is #### xyz

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a field like this:

```
<input id="tb" type="text" name="userName" value="abc"/>
```

And you wanted to get the name attribute in JQuery, it would look like this:

```
$('#tb').attr("name");
```

However your inputs are malformed and they do not have Id's or Classes, and looping through them would be extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".blah").find($("input:text")).each(function(){         
    alert("Value inside "+$(this).attr("name")+" is #### " + this.value);     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what your question is. However, to get the name of the control you are selecting:

```
var nameValue = $('.blah').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has a bunch of error, first fix those errors and to get the name of any input field just say

```
$("inputIdOrValidSelector").attr('name');
```

Try this

```
      <div class="blah">
          <p>he he he</p>
          <input type="text" name="userName" value="abc"/>
          <input type="text" name="id" value="xyz"/>
        </div>

 $(document).ready(function(){

    var pValue = $(".blah").find("p").html();
    alert(" Information in Paragraph tag is ### " + pValue);

    $(".blah").find($("input:text")).each(function(){
        alert("Value inside the " + this.name + " is " + this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("Value inside the userName is " + $("input:text[name=userName]").val());
alert("Value inside the id is " + $("input:text[name=id]").val());
```

Working demo - http://jsbin.com/aruhej

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object from within your `each` call corresponds to the `input` element from the DOM.  This element has the name attribute available on it.  For example:

```
    alert("Value inside the " + this.name + " is #### " + this.value);
```

I've created [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongritman/HZyRC/) of this code as well.